# Equivalent of struct members in Python (mainly for documentation and reading code)

Tags: python, documentation, member

It would be helpful to document the (private -> _x) data members of 
a class in the same way I can say:

```
struct foo {
  foo* p_a /* Documentation */
  foo ** pp_b /* Documentation */
};
```

But for Python (arguably we are in a different programming 
model here) what is the preferred way of doing it? Implicitly 
defining them by references is not going to cut it when I want
to see immediately what this class models.

This would also be useful for direct conversion to UML 
diagrams etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, Python *is* a different programming model. The thing to understand is, in Python, when you see this:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
```

It's not *really* a "class declaration." It's more of a "class creation." At the instant that the interpreter reaches the `class..` line, and not before, a **class object** is created and made ready. And one thing about this class object is that is basically *knows nothing about its instances*.

The only time that the class has access to the instances (and data members are usually on the instances) is when it's actually running through a method. This syntax:

```
def bar(self, x):
    ...
```

is interesting. The **explicit** first argument is kind of a hint that something different is going on. That's right: when you write `instance.bar(x)`, what's really happening is `Foo.bar(instance, x)`.

Meaning that `Foo`'s only chance at getting at the instance is with methods.

So if you want an *explicit* class model, your best bet may be to list it out - explicitly - in the `__init__` method.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None  # Bar is an important "private" member
        self._baz = None  # As is baz
        self._fizzbuzz = 4  # Of course, you can also provide defaults here
```

If I'm way off base here, I'd like to be corrected - but this is how I understand Python currently.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and this is the way I am currently doing it

Comment: @MatthiasHueser: As a side note, if you'd like to do introspection at runtime on an object's data model, you can check the `__dict__` attribute of the instance. For example, in the class I gave, the `__dict__` attribute would be `{'_bar': None, '_baz': None, '_fizzbuzz': 4}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a docstring (triple-quoted string) as the first statement in a class or method; the closest thing to a standard format for docstrings is specified as [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

```
class foo( object ):
    """
    This is a foo.
    _a is foo's a; there are many like it but this one is foo's.
    _b is foo's b and demons may fly out of your nose if you modify it.
    """

    def __init__( self ): ...
```

Comment: I considered this but this encourages having the documentation separate from the definition. This is not good practice and will lead to house-keeping issues. This might be a problem inherent in the dynamic typing of Python. A related issue is to avoid accidental 'definition and storage allocation' of members when i refer f.e to member f0o in a function where I have misspelled the 0

Comment: Well, volthos' solution suggests that it's not a problem inherent to Python, and would be my second choice for documenting the members of an object. The `__init__()` of most Python classes should initialize all the members that will be used (adding members later is, of course, possible and sometimes useful, but it is, let's say, "undisciplined"), so it's a good place to document them.